# How to detect if Symbol is supported on the current environment?

Tags: javascript

How can Symbol support be safely checked in browser and older versions of Node without breaking? Doing a `typeof Symbol` throws a ReferenceError

Comment: It’s impossible for `typeof something` to throw a `ReferenceError`. Please [edit] your question and show your _actual_ JavaScript code.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code please.

Comment: @Xufox of course `typeof` can throw a ReferenceError: http://es-discourse.com/t/why-typeof-is-no-longer-safe/15

Comment: @Xufox another case https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should NOT throw a ReferenceError:

```
if (typeof Symbol !== 'function') console.log('Symbol is not supported');
```

If you're seeing a ReferenceError it is due to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.Symbol !== undefined`. Generally speaking, you can always check for “global” variables as properties of the `window` object.